# repackaging exceptions, or keep them intact?

Tags: c++, exception

I'm writing some class which has 2 (main) subsystems. A part depends on boost::filesystem while another part depends on tinyxml. (Basically, it reads an xml, and depending on the data of the xml it uses `boost::filesystem`'s functions for more access to other files).

Now both of these are "likely" to throw exceptions. I am wondering how to handle these exceptions:

The class itself -in most circumstances- can't "fix" an exception and has just to throw it back. (Most probable case would be a faulty input from the user).

However what should one do in such a case? - `boost::filesystem` & tinyxml both have their own exceptions, which aren't completely compatible with each other.

Should I just expect the user of this class to handle boost/tinyxml exceptions? - So far the whole usage of these libraries is hidden for the end user.

Should I repackage the extensions into my own? I'm always hesitant of repackaging, as it means a lot of extra try ... catch blocks.

What do you recommend me?

Comment: ""likely"", in quotation marks? What do you mean? Does the code permit exceptions to be thrown or not? [Here is a previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372732/exception-catching-when-not-to-catch-them/7372866#7372866) of mine on the subject.

Comment: with likely I mean: there's a good reason for exceptions to occur: the disk might be write-protected, the input paths might be faulty, there might be corrupt files etc etc. These things might occur so much thus should not be a reason for the whole application to crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to answer this question without an understanding of your code and your coding guidelines, specifically as they relate to exceptions.

But if your coding guidelines permit exceptions, then I suggest a general rule-of-thumb:

Allow exceptions to propagate until they reach a context in which they can be handled properly.  If they never reach a context in which they can be handled properly, allow your program to crash.  Get a core dump and debug the problem.

"Handling" an exception in a certain context might be as simple as translation it in to an error code or your own exception class, but in this case you should rethrow the new exception and allow it to propagate to a handler.

Don't implement any form of a catch-all handler for exceptions with the intent of preventing your application from crashing, or even to log the error and die.  Instead, implement a system which will generate dumps in the event of an unhandled exception, and let your program die.  The dump itself is enough of a log.  You don't want a catch-all because your system is in such a corrupted state that it can't be recovered from.

Comment: Well the main goal of the program (at the moment) is handling (merging, splitting) some "specific" xml files. The end user would give the main xml file -> tinyxml might crash when giving a nonexisting file. The xml file will hold links to other files -> boost::filesystem is used for handling this and might crash.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend your class throws your own exceptions. This way you can enforce information hiding and your class clients won't depend from the libraries you decide to use.

Answer (score 0):

Do you believe it is relevant to the end-user? Because this is something related to design.

Some libraries when used on windows have their own data, while you can use other error handling methods for verifying. For example, sqlite has its own group of error codes, but you can use GetLastError in order to know why the database was not open.

In your case, the question is: Will you use exceptions in your own class? In this case, its better to provide your own exception. If not, you can permit the user to cach your errors and the exception if he wants to.

Claudio.

Comment: "If not, you can permit the user to cach your errors and the exception if he wants to." - What you mean with that?

Comment: Well, some APIs like the Windows API do not work with exceptions (Win32 API). The API's user can decide if he or she will treat those errors or not (e.g. using GetLastError or return values).