# Exceptions - for user notifications or error logging?

Tags: php, exception, error-handling

I'm trying to figure out what exceptions should be used for; logging application errors, or displaying user errors, and if both, how should I distinguish between and handle a user error (e.g. failed login) and an application error (e.g. a failure to connect to the database) with exceptions.

**For example, let's say a user attempts to login, but fails (user error):**

```
if(!$user->login($_POST)) {
    //$user->login() throws an Exception, throw new Exception("failed login"), on fail.
    catch(Exception $e) {
      print $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

**Or perhaps a database error occurs (error logging):**

```
public function query($query) {
$this->resource = mysql_query($query) or throw new Exception("Database error:" . mysql_error());
}
```

Which of the above two examples would be an appropriate use case, if either?

Comment: Check out this question's top answer: [Why and how would you use Exceptions in this sample PHP code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935490/why-and-how-would-you-use-exceptions-in-this-sample-php-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exceptions are for signalling *exceptional behaviour* on part of your program. During normal operation, your program should *not* usually throw exceptions at all. Something like a failed login is a normal result of your login mechanism, not an exception.

<sub>[A failed login may be an exception on the *user*'s end (if the user had reason to expect the login to work unconditionally)!]</sub>

Typical exceptional situations are running out of memory, running out of disk space, an error in the database connection, or an error during reading or writing a file. All those are things that you would normally expect to work, so an error there is an exceptional condition.

See [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7372866/596781) for more details.